# What does 余裕がない actually mean?

Tags: meaning, translation

The characters are carrying a heavy object. However, now they are standing in place (with the object) and doing nothing, so one of them asks the other character:

> 動いてもよいか?俺もそこまで余裕がない

Why is 余裕がない used here?

Comment: Can you add more context? are they in a narrow or cramped place?

Comment: No, but the thing is really heavy and he wants to move it

Comment: Please always try to explain what you have researched so far since we do not accept direct translation requests. And remember that you're supposed to accept an answer unless you really want to indicate you're dissatisfied.

Answer (score 2):

余裕がない simply means the speaker does not have much physical capacity left to continue holding the heavy object. I don't know why they're standing still, but he is suggesting that they start moving again to finish the task quickly.

Answer (score 2):

余裕がない just means “can’t afford”, so its interpretation is contextual.

He may simply state that he no longer has enough power and “can’t afford” to keep lifting the object. He may have the urge to go use the bathroom and “can’t afford” to remain at the place. He may have no longer enough mental leeway to spend time doing nothing and “can’t afford” to keep calm and being nice to others. Or he may intend something different. It’s all by context.

Answer (score -4):

'余裕がな' by itself approximates to 'wish I/we/you had time/ability'. 'い' at the end of that approximates to 'I/we/you don't have time/ability, but wish I/we/you did'. This alone answers your question. However, I will derive the full dialogue's meaning below:

The 'そこまで' before that makes the meaning 'I/we/you don't have time/ability to go that far, but wish I/we/you did'. The 'も' before all that makes the meaning 'I/we/you don't have time/ability to go further, but I wish I/we/you did'. The '俺' makes the subject of that part the speaker (I), which makes the meaning so far 'I don't have time/ability to go further, but wish I did'. Finally, The first sentence (the question) means 'Have I/we moved/carried [the object] far enough?'

So, the sentence's full meaning, based on the situation, is "Have I/we moved it far enough? I am unable to go further, but wish I was.", or "Have we moved it far enough? I wish I could go further, but can't." if we take liberties to make it sound like natural English.

Source: I pieced together the full meaning using rikaikun, a browser extension that detects and highlights segments of Japanese text and gives a ton of options for each syllable combination to help determine a text's exact meaning, or at least the root meaning. I have a great amount of experience using it, and have become very good at understanding its syntax and interpreting possible meanings. I commonly use it to translate the lyrics of Japanese music or anime openings by knowing the transcript.

My most recent project is BURN, the opening theme of Yashahime: Princess Half Demon's second 'season' (there are 3 theme songs used throughout the series, with the second one being this song). I do this as a hobby, and haven't worked on it in a while, but have the first 5 lines translated accurately, and just had real life issues preventing me from working on it further.